# Why do we Wrap recycler view into nested scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

My question is why do wrap recycler view into nested scroll view

Does it relate to smooth scroll of recycler view

Actually i am creating app which fetch 2 images and the scroll of recycler view in that is very slow so should i wrap it into nested scroll view for smooth flow or compress images and store them 
I am a bit confused on this topic ?

Comment: You should never nest scrolalble views, or you will face scroll-fighting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping Recycler view in scroll view is like a two sided blade. You should be careful about using it.

because when you use it, the recycler view will loose its advantage of recycling unneeded rows so at the same time you will have references to all those view, so if you have rows with many graphical item it will make problem for slow devices.

If you see putting the recycler view inside another nested scrollview solved your speed problem, It means you do a mess in the adapter of recycler view.

Do not do any heavy process in adapters and onBindViewHolder

Comment: I am using firebase recycler adapter 

And if not nested scroll view then what can make flow smooth